# Examples of infinite non-cancellative commutative semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I'm looking for examples of infinite non-cancellative commutative semigroups.  The only example I have readily at hand is the monoid of homeomorphism classes of closed surfaces.  Can anyone provide other examples?

Ideally, I'm interested in examples that do not have an absorbing element and that don't consist entirely of idempotents.

Comment: Take any infinite set $X$, fix some element $0\in X$ and define $xy=0$. This is the simplest one that I can think of. Or take a lattice $L$ (say, the integers with the usual order, or some power of it to get something more interesting) and define $xy=\operatorname{min}(x,y)$. Or take some infinite set $S$, $X=\mathcal{P}(X)$ its power set and define $AB=A\cap B$ (this is a subexample of the previous one). I'll stop here.

Comment: @Luiz Those are nice examples, and they've reminded me of some properties that I'm especially interested in.  I'll edit my question to reflect this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case with non-idempotents and withouth absorbing elements is more interesting. We can "mix" some of the previous examples.

Take any infinite commutative, non-cancelative semigroup $K$, and any semigroup $L$ without an absorbing element. Then the product $L\times K$ has the desired properties.

For example, $X=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$ with operation $(x,k)(y,l)=(xy,\operatorname{min}(k,l))$.

Comment: I think it is nice to explain where that comes from: A general rule states that "a product structure has some property if and only if every factor structure has the same property" (depending on the kind of structure, and the property, obviously), so to find a structure which does *not* have some set of properties, find structures which do not have each property, one at a time, and take their product.

Comment: Hey, Luiz, do you have any examples handy that don't arise from products?